# stop compilation when there is an error with bibtex

Tags: bibtex

Suppose I write the code:

```
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{eqution}
```

compilation will stop because of the `eqution` in the 3rd line.

It does not happen with `bibtex` (at least not to me): sometimes I write `titl` and such, but the compilation doesn't stop, there are only warnings (which I usually skip...). The result is an incomplete entry, like this:

[image]

Is it possible to (automatically) stop the compilation when there are such errors?

I use windows 7 and 8.1, both with the most recent versions of mikTeX and TeXworks.

In my preamble I have:

`\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=numeric-comp, bibstyle=science, sorting=none]{biblatex}`

bibliographic entry are in a separated file: I include it with `\printbibliography`.

Comment: once the `.bib` file has been converted to the form input to latex it's not possible to stop the latex compilation.  *not* ignoring the bibtex warnings is probably the best advice here.

Comment: You can add as many fields as you want to a `.bib` entry, named as you like; BibTeX will consider only those fields whose name is mandatory or optional for the entry type as specified by the `.bst` in use. A field called `titl` will not raise an error, just like `summary` wouldn't. If `title` is mandatory (it usually is), you'll just get a warning for the missing field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the syntax for an entry in a `.bib` file is

```
@ENTRY{<key>,
  <field1> = {<data>},
  <field2> = {<data>},
  <field3> = {<data>},
  <field4> = {<data>},
  ...
  <fieldn> = {<data>},
}
```

If the `ENTRY` type for `key` is not defined in the `.bst` file in use, BibTeX will issue a warning such as

```
Warning--entry type for "key" isn't style-file defined
```

if `\cite{key}` is used in the document.

The fields in an entry can be as many as you want, named as you like. For each of the entry types a `.bst` style defines, there are *mandatory* and *optional* fields. Other fields will be ignored. So, if you have

```
titl={A title},
```

this will be considered an ignored field and you'll simply get a warning such as

```
Warning--empty title in key
```

because the `title` field is missing and the `titl` field will be ignored.

There's no way to make BibTeX stop at warnings.

Comment: `biblatex` doesn't use `.bst` files, does it? (Even with `bibtex` as the backend?)

Comment: @cfr Yes, it does: there's a `biblatex.bst` style in the `biblatex` distribution. BibTeX can't work without loading a `.bst`, that style is automatically chosen if `backend=bibtex` is specified.